# Why is the angle of incidence equal to angle of reflection?

Tags: optics, reflection

This is true experimentally, but how do I prove this?

Comment: Starting from what? As you wrote, this is true experimentally. Every proof would use some experimental fact and some experimentally-based theory.

Comment: Are you looking for a derivation from, for example, Maxwell's equations?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675527/proof-that-angle-of-incidence-is-equal-to-angle-of-reflection-geometrically **and** https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451874/why-is-angle-of-incidence-equal-to-angle-of-reflection/451875